# R Extract unique rows conditional on other columns' differences

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Country   A        B                         C

HONDURAS PL  Partido Liberal              12.00000

HONDURAS PN  Partido Nacional de Honduras 17.33000

NICARAGUA PN Partido Nacional             12.00000

CHILE    PN  Partido Nacional             17.33000

HONDURAS PNH Partido Nacional             17.33000

HONDURAS PNH Partido Nacional de Honduras 17.33000
```

I am performing a merge with another dataframe, and in order to do so, I need to take only unique parties. Therefore, from this section of the dataframe, I need to take only 1 of these "HONDURAS Partido Nacional" duplicates as the unique observation (it doesn't matter which one, first occrance would suffice). The problem is some parties have the same abbreviation or "C" value. So, I need only unique observations of equivalents within country. The desired output would therefore be the following:

```
Country   A        B                         C

HONDURAS PL  Partido Liberal              12.00000

HONDURAS PN  Partido Nacional de Honduras 17.33000

NICARAGUA PN Partido Nacional             12.00000

CHILE    PN  Partido Nacional             17.33000
```

This way, even though the Nicaragua and Honduras "Partido Nacional"s have the same abbreviation, they are both retained because they are different countries and even though Chile and Honduras's "Partido Nacional"s have the same "C" value, they are retained because the country is different. Essentially, I need unique observations of when Country-A-C match (but there are multiples of B for that set), or when Country-B-C match (but there are multiples of A for that set).

Comment: For row 2 (Partido Nacional de Honduras) and 5 (Partido Nacional) neither *A* nor *B* matches. They only match in *Country* and *C* which makes it difficult to remove one of them with either *Country-A-C* or *Country-B-C*.

Comment: @AndreWildberg I see. Is it perhaps possible to use the fact that rows 5 and 6 match, to eliminate row 5, and then because rows 2 and 6 match, to keep only one of them?

Comment: That depends on the sorting of the rows which you shouldn't rely on. You could do a fuzzy match of B though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  distinct(Country, C, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
   Country  A                            B     C
1  HONDURAS PL              Partido Liberal 12.00
2  HONDURAS PN Partido Nacional de Honduras 17.33
3 NICARAGUA PN             Partido Nacional 12.00
4     CHILE PN             Partido Nacional 17.33
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `agrep`

```
# Get matching Parties
df$olap <- sapply(df$B, function(x) paste(unique(agrep(x, df$B, value=T))))

# Get overlaps
df$olap_num <- sapply(df$olap, function(x) grep(paste0(x, collapse="|"), df$olap))

df
    Country   A                            B     C
1  HONDURAS  PL              Partido Liberal 12.00
2  HONDURAS  PN Partido Nacional de Honduras 17.33
3 NICARAGUA  PN             Partido Nacional 12.00
4     CHILE  PN             Partido Nacional 17.33
5  HONDURAS PNH             Partido Nacional 17.33
6  HONDURAS PNH Partido Nacional de Honduras 17.33
                                            olap      olap_num
1                                Partido Liberal             1
2                   Partido Nacional de Honduras 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
3 Partido Nacional de Honduras, Partido Nacional 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
4 Partido Nacional de Honduras, Partido Nacional 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
5 Partido Nacional de Honduras, Partido Nacional 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
6                   Partido Nacional de Honduras 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Get unique entries by checking *Country*, *C* and whether overlaps exists in *olap_num*. This avoids removal of parties that just have the same country and value by chance.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  distinct(Country, C, olap_num, .keep_all=T) %>% 
  select(-c(olap, olap_num))
    Country  A                            B     C
1  HONDURAS PL              Partido Liberal 12.00
2  HONDURAS PN Partido Nacional de Honduras 17.33
3 NICARAGUA PN             Partido Nacional 12.00
4     CHILE PN             Partido Nacional 17.33
```